# docker one of the containers shuts down immediately

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to learn Docker, and I'm trying to create a simple CRUD application using MariaDB and Go.
I created a `Dockerfile` for Go:

```
FROM golang:1.17

WORKDIR /src/app

COPY . .

# RUN go get -u github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql \
#     go get -u github.com/gin-gonic/gin

RUN go build -o app .

CMD [ "./app" ]
```

And I also have a docker-compose so I can start MariaDB container and the Go container:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    container_name: appdb
    image: mariadb:latest
    volumes:
      - ./dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/data
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "1234"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "crudapp"
      MYSQL_USER: "root"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "root"
  
  app:
    container_name: crudapi
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    depends_on:
      - db
```

When I run `docker-compose up` the `appdb` container starts, but the `crudapi` does not. It seems like it starts and then shuts down, because I have exit code 0 in the console.
I search the web but couldn't figure out why this is happening.
I saw I should try and add `tty:true` to the `docker-compose` file but it also didn't work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you run the command `docker ps -a` you should be able to see the stopped container and it's name. Then do `docker logs <container name>` to see the log. Hopefully that tells you what is wrong.

Comment: Your container is exiting because the go application is exiting.

Comment: @HansKilian Thanks, I tried running it, but the table was empty.

Comment: @Paolo Thanks, I saw that this may be the issue, but the go app does not exiting, I checked that.

Comment: Is it possible for you to show us the logs?

Comment: My read of the situation is the same as @Paolo's: it really seems like the Go application is exiting, successfully (it's reached the end of its `main()` function).  Can you edit the question to include enough of the application code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: share us the log of your api `docker logs crudapi` and the source code to run it and help you.  Hide sensitive information

Answer (score 0):

`depends_on` does not wait for the db to be ready before starting your app, so on startup Compose does not wait until a container `appdb` is “ready” (whatever that means for your particular application) - only until it’s running.

In practice, you have to implement a check in your application code, both at startup and whenever a connection is lost for any reason and you can also include a [wait-for like tool](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it).

Comment: Thanks, I removed ```depends_on``` but I still got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Container won't wait for db to start. You have to add the Timeout in your app. Or implement logic for checking in for loop till the db container is started up.

Or you can use the script described here - [Docker control startup script](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)